# Composer install cant find composer.json

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

I am trying to just install composer, I am on mac osx. I have done it before using the terminal lines from their site and it worked just fine. I got a clean install on my mac now, and it won't install properly.

I tried to:

```
cd ~
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

and and:

```
cd /Applciations/MAMP/htdocs
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

and neither works. (I saw a post saying I should `cd` to a directory before trying to install it. But no matter what, I keep hitting this error:

```
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

when trying to install composer.

Comment: you need to use sudo. so it would be > sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

Comment: @unixmiah nope, still same issue

Comment: Do you end up with a `composer.phar` file in the directory? If not, check your PHP CLI is working correctly and is not throwing warnings about timezone.

Comment: hmn.. try > sudo curl -sS getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php

Comment: There is a typo here: `cd /Applciations/MAMP/htdocs`, but I'm guessing that happened when writing the question.

Comment: @unixmiah still does the same thing

Comment: @JacobBudin yes sorry, that I made a mistake while writing the question

Comment: I find it rather unlikely that `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` caused a "could not find `composer.json` file" error.. Are you omitting a step here? Perhaps the `php composer.phar install` command that would actually produce that error? Did you try the alternative `php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php`?

Comment: I just tried "sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php" on my CentOS dist box, it worked.

Comment: this may be for obvious reasons, if you wiped everything clean and got a clean install on OSx I'm guessing you don't have proper permissions or you need to set that up and re-try it.

Comment: I had same problem, I solved it by `php composer.phar init`. This command makes a `composer.json` file in some steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question arises from a slight misunderstanding. Composer installs itself when you run the script provided on their Web site. No additional work to install Composer is necessary.

`$ php composer.phar install` is used to install *packages* with Composer, which are almost always listed in a JSON file named `composer.json`. Without this file, Composer doesn't know which packages to install and fails.

See ["Declaring Dependencies"](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#declaring-dependencies) in Composer's [Getting Started](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) guide for how to generate a `composer.json` for your project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a deprecated error being output from PHP. Apparently that causes composer to fail detecting the composer.json file.